How to map small and dense floating islands?
Let's assume that there is a certain area that extends for hundreds of kilometers horizontally and tens of kilometers vertically, filled with thousands and thousends of static floating islands ranging in size from tens of meters to kilometers. The average distance between islands is comparable to the size of the islands themselves, with smaller ones usually more densely packed than larger ones. The islands are connected by many bridges, towers and other structures, and there is good air traffic between them.
All this forms a rather complex three-dimensional environment, which raises the question: how does the civilization living here navigate and map this environment?
While the abundance of visual cues means that an individual aircraft is likely to be able to approximate its location and navigate to its destination, actual maps and terrain diagrams may be needed to organize air routes, build infrastructure, and so on, and also in order to find the road when moving without aircraft, through bridges. Obviously, it would be easy for a technologically advanced society to create interactive digital maps and use them everywhere, but how were maps made before the invention of computers?
Even though the world in question has a small amount of "magic" necessary for its existence (like the fact that there are floating islands), I would have preferred answers that relied on more realistic methods.

"The average distance between islands is comparable to the size of the islands themselves..." A detail for further development: given how closely packed the islands are, ones lower down will get significantly less sunlight, simply because they are shaded by higher islands. It seems likely that high islands will specialise in agriculture, and low ones in industry. The social effects will be significant.

Are the islands static or do they move around?

@JohnDallman The lack of sunlight is a problem, so I simply removed the sun and made the air itself glow to provide the lower islands with enough light

@John The islands are static, it's written in the question

I think you can look up how caves are mapped

SF tag suggest it is a question about current or future tech level, right? Not past/fantasy scenario?

@EnganK: Having the air glowing brightly enough to power agriculture raises lots of new questions, and justifying the science-fiction tag without there being a lot of heat produced is going to be hard.

@JohnDallman Just consider it one of the "magical" things that is necessary for the existence of the world and just works. After all, floating islands are also impossible in reality. And this does not affect the main essence of the issue.

@Archelaos The description of the tag does not indicate that it implies future high technology. This world mainly considers the realistic (as far as possible) development of civilization in non-standard conditions (these conditions will significantly influence the technology and culture of the world, but this is also unimportant within the framework of the question), so I thought that calling it “science fiction” would be correct. If you think it's better to use other tags for this, I'll edit the question.

@EnganK: You're well past a small amount of "magic". I'd give up on claiming this is science fiction, and switch it to rationalised fantasy.

@JohnDallman: I call it "magic" because I can't think of a better term. While this could be considered magic for all practical purposes (particularly for not having to explain how some things work), in-universe it is explained by the incredibly advanced technology of the other civilization that created this world, so I don't think that calling it fantasy is correct.

@EnganK: Two things: (1) We can't read your mind, and this is the first time you've mentioned the incredibly advanced technology of the other civilization that created this world. You left us to conclude this was natural, or "magic." (2) Having wonderful technology doesn't get you round the laws of thermodynamics. If the air is glowing, and supplying lots of energy in the form of light, there is unavoidably going to be some waste heat.

@JohnDallman: 1) Well, the word "magic" in quotes implies that it's not magic in the usual sense, although maybe I should have phrased it differently. 2) I can just say that they have "magical" technology that somehow prevents the world from overheating. This is the part of the world that is inherently unrealistic (along with the fact that it's hard to maintain a breathable atmosphere over a large vertical range, or again, that the islands are floating), so I'm not going to go into detail about how and why it works, instead focusing on how the world would evolve under such conditions.

@EnganK: A suggestion. Don't have the air glow. Instead, have the undersides of the islands glow. That solves the shading problem, and leaves the air transparent, in the familiar way.

@JohnDallman Quite a lot of the worldbuilding is currently based on the air glowing, and some things will be quite difficult to change, but since glowing undersides of islands seems like an easier thing to understand (and explain without breaking a lot of physics), I'll consider using that instead of the current solution


Schematic map, similar to how subway maps are drawn, with focus on paths connecting locations, rather than representing their exact positions.
Add visual cues needed for navigation.
With numbers, indicate distances or times of flight, including ascending/descending (which may differ), similarly to how estimated walking times are shown in hiking maps.

This might not be the best military map, but will be practical for commuting, travel, trade etc.

Highway systems work the same way, but instead of a centralized schematic map for riders who can't change course, it has a dispersed schematic labeling for drivers who can change course. If you want to go from some little town in California to some little town in New York, you can be more efficient with a map, but all you really need to know is how to get to the nearest big highway, how to get from the nearest big town in NY to the little town you want to go to, and a very rough approximation of the grid coordinates of you and your destination.

Stacked tracing paper with lie-flat binding
This is a problem that I've faced in my own worldbuilding project... on Airworld, all the land masses are floating some distance above the hot global sea.  Land masses of various sizes can be stacked vertically as well as being positioned in latitude and longitude.
So, the rennaisance-tech inhabitants map their world by noting both altitude and horizontal position of geographical features.
While I have mapped this using digital technology with graphics in layers that can be turned on and off, the inhabitants of Airworld would have charts drawn on translucent paper stacked into books with ring or spiral binding, so that the shadow of higher or lower land masses could still be seen while the book was opened to the altitude of most interest, and the paper would lie flat and wouldn't have to be bent (and distorted) when opened as with gathered-sheaf sewn binding.
In places where the land masses are smaller and stacked with lower vertical separation, there would be map books where each page represented a lower vertical separation than for areas where the land masses are large and have a wide vertical separation.

Pop Up Atlas!

One obvious solution is that they make 3d paper maps! Through careful slicing, folding, reinforcing & gluing techniques, they make maps that have portions "pop up" above the ground level. Traditionally, these techniques have been used for children's books and centerpiece decorations, but you can often find them in fantasy settings now as well.

Essentially, they would create a base level map, which would be your ground level. At various strategic locations, small pieces of folded paper or card stock (or parchment) are attached that, when the map is opened, unfolded, or when a tab is pulled, they fold off of the page creating a second (or third or fourth etc) layer of map.


The example isn't a map, but does show the technique in a very basic form. Essentially, the white and yellow blobby bits are your base level. The red and orange blobby bits would represent your islands as they hover above the land below.

Your cartographers would use bits of parchment or paper to fill in the holes left by cutting, and they may also use a second sheet of paper to conceal any strings or other mechanisms used to manipulate the map levels.

Let's look at what happened here on Earth in Real Life
Most of your problem is taken care of using a good old fashioned 2D map. That map can indicate topology, ocean currents and depth, all kinds of things. It solves all of your problems (including short-hop flights). But let's look at what that's become.
courtesy the PilotInstitute. Click the link for a quick introduction to reading sectional maps.
Pilot sectional maps, when looked at without practice, appear ridiculously complex. They need to be! They're conveying an enormous amount of information in a (once learned) easy-to-read format that simplifies the complexities of a 3D world such that pilots can quickly and safely navigate even the worst terrain. But even the most detailed of these maps depend, today, on additional technology.
Pre-GPS navigation
So, how did commercial, private, and military flights navigate in the U.S. before GPS? I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to research the detailed history, but here's what happened in summary:

Dead Reckoning/Contact Flying: Pilots had to familiarize themselves with landmarks (including celestial navigation) to know where they were. Landmarks included artificial marks (such as giant arrows made out of concrete). This solution works fine at slow speeds on clear days and it was the way pilots navigated for a long time. (Early Boeing 747s had a port in the roof for a sextant!)

Radio-based navigation: All you need is two radio stations with (well-) known locations and your location can be determined through straightforward triangulation. This included early RADAR solutions that used ground-based detection to inform pilots where they were. Airline passengers in the U.S. can still find old radio transponder stations dotting the U.S. and, I believe, some are still in use.

A significant leap in navigation occurred with the invention of the artificial horizon and the gyrocompass. These two devices helped pilots know what the plane was actually doing and, therefore, could focus more accurately on navigational plotting.

Advancing radiometric solutions included LORAN (LOng RAnge Navigation) and the British Decca systems. These solutions began to merge plane-based and land-based navigational aids. They advanced rapidly during the 1950s-1970s using higher and higher frequency solutions and redundancy to avoid weather problems.


Computerization came before GPS, but all it really did was automate what people were doing more-or-less by hand. With the advent of GPS, everything became automatic and (for the most part) weather-independent.

How does a 2D map accurately indicate "a rather complex 3D environment"?

@IMP9024 In the same way that 2D maps accurately indicate "rather complex 3D environement[s]" today. You seem to be under the impression that humanity did something unique and amazing before GPS. We didn't. We used 2D maps combined with radio navigation - and we did it successfully for almost 100 years. Those maps are designed to convey an enormous amount of information - including safe transit lanes. A pilot even today would be confused by your question as they're still trained on the 2D maps you don't think are sufficient. Said another way... (*Continued*)

... the way you accurately indicate a rather complex 3D environment... in fact the way you accurately indicate any complex environment from electronics to massively complex factory complexes to particle accelerators and outer space... is by reducing the complexity through ignoring what isn't important, identifing simple ways to reflect what is, and to model everything else. Heck, humanity's been simulating and modeling forever. Yeah - we've already solved this problem. You've just not been properly introduced to it.

The main issue I have with your answer is that you equate flight maps to the kind of map needed to get through the environment described by OP. Pilots don't have to worry about running into aerial obstacles, so a contour map showing all the common air routes and airports will suffice. However, when there are many pieces of rock floating that may overlap or act as airborne obstacles, the bird's eye view of a contour map is no longer useful. No doubt there is a way to map it on a 2D map, but I don't believe the flight maps you linked can fill that requirement. You mentioned massively...continued

...complex factories that can be mapped by 2D maps. I'm interested to know how this is done.

@IMP9024 You've brought up a good point. When I read "floating islands" I jumped to the conclusion of islands floating on water - which I've seen (it's fun watching the wind blow the islands, upon which animals live and trees grow, move). The OP doesn't specify if they're floating on water or the air. You've jumped to the conclusion that it's air, which might be right. But only the OP can tell us. Regardless, if they're successfully connected by bridges, the relative position between the islands changes little and my answer still works. Cities on Earth vary by altitude.

Stacked color coded maps.
Mostly these will mirror real navigation maps. the big diffrence is shade of color would be used to indicates altitude, perhaps deep red through to deep green. Real topgrpahic maps use this. Or only one or two color and use the darkness of the color as an indicator.  This is similiar to bathymetric maps where darkness of blue indicate depth.


It lets the brain easily sort them. They might even use another color gradient for wind patterns. real topographic maps use color to convey diffrent types of information.
One color might even be reserved for safe/legal routes, we see that in navigation maps.

You need a lot of maps no matter what, islands will just start to acclude each other no mattr what visualization you use. So you stack many maps, likely sorted into books up and down in the same book side to side moves you to new books. You might even need to map things like falling water.
No map is really intuitive to read and the more information they need to convey the longer it takes ot learn them, real navigation maps are not easy so your audience does not need that much detail.

Now air navigation is going to use different maps than road maps, you can't use one type of map for everything, even the earliest maps used different maps for land and sea.

It could be possible to use a contour map to outline landmasses and indicate their altitude. It would be most readable in scenarios where islands did not overlap much vertically, and it would look basically like a regular contour map of islands in a lake, but with different elevations indicated alone the island edges. This approach would face limitations where many islands are vertically stacked, as the map would become unreadable with the outlines of hundreds of 10-meter islands all stacked on top of each other. You'd also have issues displaying any relevant topography on the underside of each island. Perhaps different colored inks could be used, and the same map could display top-side or bottom-side topography, or different elevation ranges, when looked at through different colored lenses, for example. A pre-computer society would also be capable of making an anaglyphic image (red-blue 3D), giving a flat map a 3D effect when using the right glasses.
In cases where the islands are stacked and the vertical separation becomes more important, it might be necessary to use a model instead of a map. Maps are fine for our everyday navigation since the surface of the earth is a 2D manifold, but the third dimension might be needed when operating in 3D space. You'd trade convenience of a flat printed map for fidelity of representing a 3D space.
If there are a limited number of major thoroughfares, these could be drawn with a schematic representation like a cave map or a subway map. Each major island might have an island-centric map showing how to get to other major destinations.

Realistically, you need an atlas, not a map. You divide your region into slices of a certain thickness, and each page of your atlas covers a slice. A bridge going up or down from one slice to another would give a page number to turn to at the point where it leaves a given slice. For more detail, you subdivide the slices just like one of those old street atlases where you went off one page and were directed to another. (I think you can still get those?) You could also have an overview map, maybe with top and side views, that just covered the very largest islands, small enough in number that there is not too much overlap.
You would need a convention for what to do if an island with hills straddled multiple slices. I would say you pick one slice and, on the other slices that island extends into, mark gray patches with page numbers directing you to the page for that island.
All of this is assuming the islands are densely packed enough that islands near the ground would be completely obscured by numerous islands above. But it sounds like that's what you're going for.

Each little island is a dimple. Each dimple goes on the cylindrical map. Each map goes into a little music https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_box - and the melodies are learned and loved by those who dwell there and who all have perfect pitch, knowing and reproducing maps this way.

Maps, as we know it, became a thing due to the needs of long distance seafaring starting mostly in XVIth century. Later, (XVII-XVIIIth century) military operations required first precise mapping of earth. But before this time, maps were more decorative than precise. And people traveling both on land and short range over sea generally traveled from place to place. "Maps" were lists of cities and landmarks one has to pass on the way. Traveler would arrive in city X and would ask for directions how to get to city Y. While there he would ask about Z etc. Such system do not require any visual representation, and even if it is used, it takes form of a long strip with places drawn along the travel lines with some terrain features traveler may encounter on the way.
In your case the most logical "map" would be a list of island names one has to visit on the way. Only as you reach industrial age maps may start to develop starting from island plans. A lot depends on how many layers of islands are there. If only a few, this may be portrayed as a few pages in atlas showing the "layers", possibly ignoring minor differences in relative height between islands.
And in computer age you will get 3D maps.
